# Get entire text line that starts with search pattern

Tags: php, file, search

I have a .txt file full of lines that each start with a unique id in square brackets:

```
[13] Text text text text text text text
[23] Text text text text text text text
[65] Text text text text text text text
[07] Text text text text text text text 
[66] Text text text text text text text
```

With php I open and retrieve the text file content:

```
$file = 'path_to_file/file.txt';
$handle = fopen($file, "r");
$content = fread($handle, filesize($file));
fclose($handle);

$search_id = '[65]';
```

I now wish to find the individual line in `$content` that starts with the id I am searching for (`$search_id`), and retrieve only that line. The id's in square brackets (followed by a space) will always initiate the lines. When retrieving the line, I wish to strip it of this id, since I only need the text line without the id.

My questions are:

- **How do I most efficiently search this file?** (There will always be only one occurrence of the id)
- **How do I collect the line that contains the search key?** And
- **how do I remove the leading id-and-brackets to only retrieve the text line?**

Comment: Is the file subjected to change frequently or is it static?

Comment: @vivek_23 It might be changed manually now and then. The page that runs this php-code should simply retrieve the text lines every time it is run

Comment: Ok, so is the goal fast search?

Comment: If you want to retrieve fast, then have these in your DB with the ID column indexed. If you don't like it the DB way, I am afraid, line by line processing seems to be the only way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the files aren't enormous, and since you're already reading the entire file, you can use a Regular Expression:

```
$id = "07";
preg_match("/\[$id\] (.*)/", file_get_contents($file), $match);
echo $match[1];
```

- Match `[$id]` and then a space and then match everything else and capture it `(.*)`

Comment: Thank you. Seems to work well. The file may contain a few hundred lines. Would there be a speed issue?

Comment: No, even thousands should be OK.  You would need to time it.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, I suggest you use [`file`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.file.php) to get an array containing the file's lines:

```
$file = 'path_to_file/file.txt';

$search_id = '[65]';

$lines = file($file);

$text = $textWithSearchId = '';
foreach($lines as $line)
{
    if(strpos(trim($line), $search_id) === 0)
    {
        $text = trim(substr($line, strlen($search_id)));
        $textWithSearchId = $line;
    }
}
echo "$text<br />$textWithSearchId";
```

Here is a working test:

```
$lines = array();
$lines[] = "[13] Text 13 text text text text text text";
$lines[] = "[23] Text 23 text text text text text text";
$lines[] = "[65] Text 65 text text text text text text";
$lines[] = "[07] Text 07 text text text text text text";
$lines[] = "[66] Text 66 text text text text text text";

$search_id = '[65]';

$text = $textWithSearchId = '';
foreach($lines as $line)
{
    if(strpos(trim($line), $search_id) === 0)
    {
        $text = trim(substr($line, strlen($search_id)));
        $textWithSearchId = $line;
    }
}
echo "$text<br />$textWithSearchId";
```

Output:

```
Text 65 text text text text text text
[65] Text 65 text text text text text text
```

Comment: This seems to be the fastest as far as file reading is concerned.

Answer (score -1):

```
$file = 'path_to_file/file.txt';
$handle = fopen($file, "r");
$content = fread($handle, filesize($file));
fclose($handle);
$arr = explode(PHP_EOL, $content);
$search_id = '[65]';
foreach ($arr as $value) {
    $result = substr($value, 0, 4);
    if($result === $search_id) 
    {
      $string = str_replace($search_id,'', $value);
      print_r($string);
      return;
    }
}
```

Variable $string contains the output

Comment: See my edit suggestion ;) (ps. I did not downvoted)

Comment: I didn't downvote either but maybe because it is just a code dump with no explanation.

Comment: Okay but i tried to cover all the senerio 

I have updated the code kindly check ones

Comment: You rejected my edit... see it and add some text to explain your code, by doing this it'll maybe fine